# Unable to open .ism and .uip files using Installshield 2019

Tags: installshield, installanywhere

I was using InstallShield 2011 (licensed version) to build **.ism** and **.uip** InstallShield projects and create **.exe** and **.bin** files from them.  Since I was using command-in-line arguments (IsCmdBld.exe, InstallShieldUniversalCommandLineBuild.exe) with the above **.ism** and **.uip** projects to build, it's pretty easy for us to and create setup.exe and setup.bin from them.

**Our sample syntax:**

```
exec executable="${installShield.home}/IsCmdBld.exe" dir="."

arg line=' -p "../ISScript/setup.ism" -r "${release}" '

exec executable="${installShield.universal.home}/InstallShieldUniversalCommandLineBuild.exe" dir="."

arg line='"../universal/setup.uip" -build ${release}'
```

The issue was raised when we were thinking of upgradation of InstallShield to the latest version, we couldn't find the build tool (InstallShieldUniversalCommandLineBuild.exe) in the latest package. So the installers (**.bin**) creating for UNIX based platforms are stopped.

FYI: While we were using InstallShield 11 (licensed version) to create the universal installer (**.uip**) using "InstallShieldUniversalCommandLineBuild.exe" as an executable, we had a package named "Universal" in our InstallShield 11, which contained the above command line too.

We would be happy if you could help us with this.

Comment: If you're using a licensed version of InstallShield, why aren't you asking them for support?

Comment: @Ken WhiteSince the support is not available at appropriate times,and moreover the manufacturer for this product had been changed twice in this time interval; We had no other option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not completely clear what your question is, but I think it's along the lines of “How do I build a .uip project with a current offering from Flexera?” And, while I have some clarifications to offer (and I will), the bottom line is that the product that handled .uip projects was discontinued long ago, so there's likely to be some significant migration work.

In the InstallShield 11 era (2005 or so), the Windows and non-Windows branches of InstallShield were packaged together as a product called InstallShield Universal. Since then, two relevant things changed. The combined packaging was discontinued, so if you need to support both Windows and non-Windows, Flexera's products are once again separate offerings. Also, after ZeroG's InstallAnywhere joined the family, the long term result was that InstallShield Multiplatform was discontinued, and InstallAnywhere survived as the non-Windows offering.

So the important question is what sort of upgrade path there is from your .uip into InstallAnywhere. This is outside my knowledge (I just worked on the Windows side), but there is a mention of [Upgrading from InstallShield MultiPlatform](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installanywhere2018sp1/roottopic.htm#helplibrary/ia_upgradingprojects.htm#getting_started_4090317329_1111200) in the InstallAnywhere documentation. Thus I wouldn't rule it out. And once you sort that out, you'll have to adjust your build script to use either [build.exe or Ant](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installanywhere2018sp1/roottopic.htm#search-command-line%20build), by the looks of it.

Comment: Appreciate for ur reply.....The exact problem with installshield currently is that I was unable to handle(open, build and execute) .uip files(non-windows platform projects) using the latest version installshield(Which i was able to do using Installshield 11)...With addition to ur reply, I would like to mention you that I had been testing on the "InstallAnywhere 2018" linux package to find out whether the support for non-windows packages were replaced as other module, I was unable to find anything from it....

Comment: FYI: Windows application packaging works fine (conversion of .ism to .exe) using the command line tool "IsCmdBld.exe"...The only issue i was facing is i couldn't find out where is "InstallShieldUniversalCommandLineBuild.exe"(command tool for building .uip packages) available in the latest versions(Doubt whether its renamed or totally replaced with any other)....And moreover the contact numbers given by Macrovision(Developer of Installshield 11) are no longer available since the company is no more....I had even posted this issue on flexara community forum, but it is still yet to get reply

Comment: That's as I expected. The Windows product's path is direct (if long; 14 years is an eternity in software), but ISMP to IA is a total product change. Definitely focus your questions there. Porting or even upgrading may be possible, but details including how to build the resulting project (what you call converting to exe) will differ.